# Retrieve results only where ALL keywords match Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to pull users based on their tags where ALL keywords match.

Take this working code:

```
$search_terms = array('keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3', 'keyword 4');

$search_results = User::where('user_type_id', 1)
    ->where('approved', 1)
    ->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($search_terms) {
        $q->whereIn('name', $search_terms);
    })->get();
```

At the minute I am using `whereIn()` to do this, but it will pull users even if they have 1 match out of all the inputted keywords. So if we have keyword 1, keyword 2, keyword 3, keyword 4. The query should only pull results where ALL the keywords are matched in the tags table for a given user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work, could you please check

```
$search_terms = array('keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3', 'keyword 4');

$search_results = User::where('user_type_id', 1)
    ->where('approved', 1)
    ->whereHas("tags", function($q) use ($search_terms) {
        $q->whereIn("name", $search_terms);
        }, "=", count($search_terms));
    ->get();
```